# Cron Schedule to run every 15 minutes between certain datetimes

Tags: cron, cron-task, crontrigger, google-cloud-scheduler

I've got a cron expression for running every 15 minutes:

```
*/15 * * * *
```

However, I **don't** want it to run between Friday 23:00 and Sunday 19:00. How could I achieve this within a cron expression? I know I can run between certain days but I can't figure out how to add a time to that.

Anyone understand the witchcraft that is cron? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with one cron job. You'll have to split them up.

```
*/15 * * * 1-4
*/15 1-23 * * 5
*/15 19-23 * * 7
```

https://crontab.guru really helpful for setting these up.

Comment: So effectively create multiple schedules, one that runs all day (Mon-Thur) and then 2 running between certain times on Friday and Sunday? @eleytheria

Comment: Yep, edited with the other two schedules.